# Circle UIView with button to randomize it color

Tags: swift, uiview, ios8

i'm studying UIView and i'm with a problem.

I have a circle UIView where i make it using:

```
import UIKit

    class Ball: UIView {

        override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
            var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
            var randColor: UIColor = Colors.randomColor()
            randColor.setFill()

            Colors.ballColor = randColor
            Colors.colorPosition = find(Colors.arrayColors, randColor)!
            println("Randomizando -> \(Colors.colorPosition)")

            path.fill()
        }
    }
```

and i have a button that i randomize it  color calling setNeedDisplay, but drawRect function is called twice.

Randomize Func:

```
 func randomize(){
    ball.setNeedsDisplay()
 }
```

ball is an outlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var ball: Ball!




Color class:

class Colors {

    static var arrayColors = [
        UIColor.blackColor(),
        UIColor.whiteColor(),
        UIColor.grayColor(),
        UIColor.redColor(),
        UIColor.greenColor(),
        UIColor.blueColor(),
        UIColor.yellowColor(),
        UIColor.orangeColor(),
        UIColor.purpleColor(),
        UIColor.brownColor()]

    static let arrayColorsNames = [
        "Preto",
        "Branco",
        "Cinza",
        "Vermelho",
        "Verde",
        "Azul",
        "Amarelo",
        "Laranja",
        "Roxo",
        "Marrom"]


    static var ballColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    static var colorPosition: Int = -1

    static func randomColor() -> UIColor{

        if let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayColors.count))) as? Int{
            return arrayColors[randomColor]
        }

        return UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    static func randomColorName() -> String{

        if let randomColorName = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arrayColorsNames.count))) as? Int{
            return arrayColorsNames[randomColorName]
        }

        return "Azul"
    }

}
```

Button Action:

```
@IBAction func colorButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == Colors.arrayColorsNames[Colors.colorPosition]{
        println("IGUAIS")
    }
    randomize()
}
```

the problem is: The drawRect function is called twice and change 2 times the color

Comment: Show your button's IBAction method.

Comment: @DuncanC done! i edited the question and add the action on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the randomize function with this.

```
func randomize(){
    ball.backgroundColor = randomColor()
 }
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i made it static because there are in separate files but without success.

Comment: Because they are in separate classes i will update it

Comment: Yes, separate classes not files sry

Comment: @DuncanC Got the same error (on ball.setNeedsDisplay()) when i used the static. Is there another way to write it? To click a button and change the color (to a random color) of a uiview?

Comment: Just finished updating

Comment: It works, i found the solution here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28174999/swift-cant-change-color-of-circle-drawn-in-view